# Is there a way to mount a Windows shared drive so I can access those files on my phone?

Tags: wi-fi, file-system

I have a shared network drive full of files I want to access from my phone over wifi.

Is there a easy way to mount it on my phone?

I have a rooted Motorola Milestone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ASTRO File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.metago.astro) by Metago available from Google Play Store has an SMB plugin ([ASTRO SMB Module](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.metago.astro.smb)) that serves your needs.

[image: Astro File Manager Screen Shoot]

Answer (score 2):

You may give SMB File Sharing a try.

Just klick the image or scan the code.

[image]

Comment: just curious, why did you not just give the url?

Comment: @Louis the QR code is link-clickable

Comment: Exactly, i linked the QR code to a description on androidpit. But so you won't have to type the Name of the app to search it in the market, just scan it with ixmat, or whatever barcode scanner you like and you are qucikly able to install the wanted application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PaderSyncFM from the dev's [site](http://www.pader-sync.com/downloads.html)

It supports FTP, SFTP, SMB and WebDAV...