# Access PC using tablet

Tags: wi-fi, file-transfer

I have a tablet and a normal PC. I have a lot of files on my normal pc that i would like to copy to my tablet. Both the systems are connected to the same WiFi network. Is there any way to use this WiFi network to transfer files from the normal PC to the tablet?

Answer (score 1):

[WiFi File Explorer](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.dooblou.WiFiFileExplorerPRO&feature=search_result) is perfect for this! i'm using it right now, in fact! The newest version allows for uploading as well as downloading from PC to device, over wifi. I've been using this app for a while now, and i can honestly say it works perfectly, and there are good devs behind it that are updating with useful functions consistently.

Comment: Do you think.... if there is a free app that does the same thing?

Comment: there is a free version ([here](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.dooblou.WiFiFileExplorer&feature=more_from_developer)) but it does not support uploading to your device, only downloading and streaming. [SwiFTP](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.swiftp&feature=search_result) claims to do similar actions, but i don't find it as easy to use as WiFiFE. You'll have to be familiar with using ftp servers for SwiFTP.

Comment: i also recently have used [File Expert](https://market.android.com/details?id=xcxin.filexpert&feature=search_result) which allows you to access your computer over wifi fairly easily

Answer (score 1):

I share a folder from my desktop and then use [AndSMB](https://market.android.com/details?id=lysesoft.andsmb) on my Xoom to connect and copy files as needed. I have been satisfied with it so far.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably via a shared folder.  See [Is there a way to mount a Windows shared drive so I can access those files on my phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2392/is-there-a-way-to-mount-a-windows-shared-drive-so-i-can-access-those-files-on-my) for details on that.

You could also run an FTP server on your PC and use an FTP client on your tablet.

Comment: I am using ubuntu. I tried using Bluetooth. But it quite unreliable. So idecided to  use WiFi instead... since both  systems  are on the  same  wifi   network.

Comment: @Jay FTP should be pretty simple on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. But I managed to solve it using some commands I found on the Ubuntu forums at canonical. Apparently, it is possible to connect the transformer via USB. But since it shows up as an mtp device instead of a normal storage device...Ubuntu was unable to recognize it. Once I installed the necessary drivers, it was possible to mount it like a normal storage device. Of course, the only inconvenience is that I would have to type the mount and dismount commands every time I plug and unplug the Asus transformer.

I chose to do a direct USB transfer instead of wifi, cos I simply found the wifi transfers too unreliable.

None the less, thanks  to all the other answers as well. If anything I learned something  new :-)